# Scrapy - overcoming start_uri redirect by adding to allowed_urls dynamically - parse_start_url issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Hi Stackoverflow Community

I have the following problem:

I am trying to crawl a long list of websites. Some of the websites in the start_url list redirect (301). I want scrapy to crawl the redirected websites from start_url list as if they were also on the allowed_domain list (which they are not). For example, example.com was on my start_url list and allowed domain list and example.com redirects to foo.com. I want to crawl foo.com.

```
DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.foo.com/> from <GET http://www.example.com>
```

I noticed the following response [Scrapy Crawl all websites in start_url even if redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988931/scrapy-crawl-all-websites-in-start-url-even-if-redirect) 
which provides a solution by modifying the OffsiteMiddleware. That part I understand but I am unsure about how the parse_start_url is overridden. This is my code so far:

```
import scrapy
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
from placementarchitect import bingapi
import tldextract

from spiderproject.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class GoodSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "goodoldSpider"

    def __init__(self, input=None):
        self.searchterm = input
        self.urlstocrawl = bingapi.get_crawl_urls(self.searchterm) # This returns a list of crawlable sites from the BingSearchAPI
        self.start_urls = self.urlstocrawl
        self.allowed_domains = []

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        domain = tldextract.extract(str(response.request.url)).registered_domain
        if domain not in self.allowed_domains:
            self.allowed_domains.append(domain)
        else:
            return self.parse(response)

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath("//a/@href"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[attribute::class="cat-item"]'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/div/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield item

        next_page = response.css(".cat-item>a::attr('href')")
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_dir_contents)

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(GoodSpider, input='"good news"')                
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

The scrapy documentation is sparse on parse_start_url, so I am not sure how this would be implemented. As such my solution doesn't seem to work.

I am afraid this is due to how

```
def parse_start_url()
```

is implemented.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: removing `allowed_domains` isn't a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It was actually not necessary to have the:

```
def parse_start_url(...)
```

Instead, I integrated the code I previously had under **def parse_start_url(...)** into the spider's main **def parse** function:

```
import scrapy
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
from placementarchitect import bingapi
import tldextract

from spiderproject.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class GoodSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "goodoldSpider"

def __init__(self, input=None):
    self.searchterm = input
    self.urlstocrawl = bingapi.get_crawl_urls(self.searchterm) # This returns a list of crawlable sites from the BingSearchAPI
    self.start_urls = self.urlstocrawl
    self.allowed_domains = []

    print("TEST >>> In Searchscraper.py:  " + str(self.urlstocrawl))

## Commented this part out as it is not required anymore - code was integrated into def parse(..) below
# def parse_start_url(self, response):
#     domain = tldextract.extract(str(response.request.url)).registered_domain
#     print(domain)
#     if domain not in self.allowed_domains:
#         self.allowed_domains.append(domain)
#     return self.parse(response.url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    domain = tldextract.extract(str(response.request.url)).registered_domain
    print(domain)
    if domain not in self.allowed_domains:
        self.allowed_domains.append(domain)
    for href in response.xpath("//a/@href"):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[attribute::class="cat-item"]'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/div/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        yield item

    next_page = response.css(".cat-item>a::attr('href')")
    if next_page:
        url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_dir_contents)

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(GoodSpider, input='"good news"')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

This solution dynamically adds domains that our initial start_url s redirect to the allowed_domains list.

This means that all other domains will be filtered as follows:

```
[scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.pinterest.com': <GET http://www.pinterest.com/goodnewsnetwork/>
```

Comment: Hi,
how would you implement this into a CrawlSpider?