# Don't allow redirects - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, bots

I have a scraper which if it need to access the website it need login authentication, or need to be redirected to a captcha verification page, the website is using react, can I use any python library to stop that? I am using selenium.
mobile.yangkeduo.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python selenium: possible to cancel redirect on driver.get()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775048/python-selenium-possible-to-cancel-redirect-on-driver-get)

Comment: @user15270287 thanks, but no it doesn't.