# How to crawl given urls instead of redirected ones in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to crawl from [this page](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_il_ti_computers?fst=as%3Aon&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A541966%2Cn%3A565108%2Ck%3Alaptop&keywords=laptop&ie=UTF8&qid=1445324322&lo=computers) from Amazon, but scrapy always direct me to [another page](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=laptop&lo=none) whose images are smaller than the first page. Thus I want to stop redirecting and crawl the first page.

After some search, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795416/how-to-handle-302-redirect-in-scrapy). But when I changed my code like this:

```
yield Request(item['link'],meta = {
                  'dont_redirect': True,
                  'handle_httpstatus_list': [301,302]
              }, callback=self.parse)
```

Tough it stops redirecting, but it doesn't parse the first page either! My log is like this:

```
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: amazon)
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'amazon.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['amazon.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'amazon'}
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpProxyMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: AmazonPipeline
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-20 14:56:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-10-20 14:56:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_il_ti_computers?rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A!493964%2Cn%3A541966%2Cn%3A565108%2Cp_n_size_browse-bin%3A7817231011&ie=UTF8&qid=1445324149&lo=computers> (referer: None)
2015-10-20 14:56:41 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-10-20 14:56:41 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 361,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 423,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 20, 6, 56, 41, 743646),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 20, 6, 56, 40, 868227)}
```

Anyone has any idea about this? Thx!

Comment: If the server decides to send you a redirect header without returning an actual body, then of course avoiding the redirect will make you not see anything. If you find Amazon redirecting your scraper all the time, then you should try to figure out what makes them do that.

Comment: @poke Thanks, I really have no idea why the server keeps doing this, the first page can be viewed in the browser with no trouble.

Comment: Servers often look at the HTTP headers that are sent in the request. You can try sending the same stuff that your browser sends to emulate it completely; and then remove one header at a time until you figure out which header makes the servers react in that way.

Comment: @poke I am sending the full url my browser sends to the server now, but it  redirects to another page automatically.

Comment: I’m talking about the [HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), not the URL.

Answer (score 0):

What function are you calling with callback=self.parse?

Comment: You should post your Spider type and parse function here. Some Spiders won't work if you overwrite their default parse function.