# Scrapy not picking up my url

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy code that should be able to take on phone and addresses from a table within a web:

```
import scrapy

class PeopleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name="People"
 start_urls=[
  'http://canada411.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/519-896-7080/',
 ]
 def parse(self,response):
  for people in response.css("div.person-search__table--row"):
   yield {
    'Name': people.css('div.person-search__table--name::text').extract_first(),
    'Phone Number': people.css('div.person-search__table--phoneNumber::text').extract_first(),
    'Street': people.css('div.person-search__table--name::street').extract_first(),
    'City': people.css('div.person-search__table--city::text').extract_first(),
    'Province': people.css('div.person-search__table--province::text').extract_first(),
    'Postal Code': people.css('div.person-search__table--postalCode::text').extract_first(),
   }
```

But I keep getting 0 crawled pages...

```
scrapy runspider get.py -o people.json
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'people.json'}
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-02-15 20:14:26 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-02-15 20:14:27 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://99.227.194.212/> from <GET http://canada411.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/519-896-7080/>
2017-02-15 20:14:27 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://99.227.194.212/login.html> from <GET http://99.227.194.212/>
2017-02-15 20:14:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://99.227.194.212/login.html> (referer: None)
2017-02-15 20:14:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-02-15 20:14:27 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 681,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 7931,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 16, 1, 14, 27, 273208),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 16, 1, 14, 26, 788223)}
2017-02-15 20:14:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Is there a problem with my code? Or is the url not able to be parsed?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `Redirecting (302)` message when you try to crawl the url, which means you're being sent away from the page you're trying to crawl. You'll need to add a meta value to stop the redirect; see [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795416/how-to-handle-302-redirect-in-scrapy) for a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are scraping Yellopages website and its not easy to scrape them.

I am sure they are redirecting to the captcha page. I have scraped that website in the past.

You can try this piece of code to see what page is that redirecting to.

```
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

def parse_details(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

It will open the scraped URL in browser (if you are running this scrapy project on Ubuntu, Windows or Mac)