# How to allow scrapy to follow redirects?

Tags: python, redirect, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from historical versions of web pages as backed up Wayback Machine.

I have thousands of pages that need scraping and I don't want to go to trouble of finding out exact dates and time of available backups for each of them. I just want to get weekly historical data or the nearest available.

What I know is that if I put a date in a link here:

`https://web.archive.org/web/<some_date>/<some_url>`

then Wayback Machine will automatically redirect to the closest available capture. This will work fine in my scenario.

I have a `scrapy` spider that extracts the data and that I already successfully used on the current version of web pages, so I know that it works and it produces the correct output. But when I try to run scrapy on the backed up versions of pages I get the following output notifying that the page is redirecting and no data is returned:

```
2023-05-04 20:18:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-05-04 20:18:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-05-04 20:18:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-05-04 20:18:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-05-04 20:18:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-05-04 20:18:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20200204105913/<some_url>> from <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20050313/<some_url>>
```

I've looked at other questions of similar nature and I understand I need to do something with the middleware, but those other questions were more about not allowing redirects, while I want the exact opposite.

How do I allow `scrapy` to follow redirects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to handle 302 redirect in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795416/how-to-handle-302-redirect-in-scrapy)

Comment: @SuperUser, no it's the exact opposite. The question and the answer are both about not allowing redirects while what I asked is how to handle redirects correctly. I've seen most of similar answers before as I pointed out in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation link @beer provided](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect), you need to enable the `RedirectMiddleware`.

However, from the documentation :

> For example, if you want the redirect middleware to ignore 301 and 302
> responses (and pass them through to your spider) you can do this:
>
> ```py
> class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
>     handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302]
> ```

This parameter is used to **bypass the `RedirectMiddleware`** for the given HTTP statuses. Try using the middleware without setting `handle_httpstatus_list`.

Comment: Oh yes! That fixed it! I enabled `RedirectMiddleware` in settings and commented out `handle_httpstatus_list` and it's working now. Sort of. Now gotta solve the issue that the website has changed quite a bit over time so my scraper only successfully gets data from last few years only. In hindsight I should've expected it to happen...

Answer (score 1):

try `RedirectMiddleware`

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect

set

`handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302]`

Comment: When I do this, it looks like the spider is ignoring redirects rather than follow them.