# Getting : Crawled (302) while scraping laptop data using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I want to scrape data like screen type and title etc from https://www.newegg.com/tools/laptop-finder
but I am stuck as my script gets crawled but not scraped

HTML code of the website is

```
<tr>
    <td class="td-item">
        <a class="goods-info" href="https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16834156430?Item=N82E16834156430" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-pc-builder-pdp">
            <div class="goods-img">
                <img src="https://c1.neweggimages.com/ProductImageCompressAll125/34-156-430-03.jpg" alt="MSI Katana 15 B12VGK-082US 15.6&quot; Gaming Laptop">
            </div>
            <div class="goods-title">
                <div class="goods-title-content">MSI Katana 15 B12VGK-082US 15.6" Gaming Laptop</div>
                <div class="goods-rating">
                    <i class="rating rating-4" aria-label="rated 4 out of 5"></i>
                    <span class="goods-rating-num font-s text-gray">(31)</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Screen Size</div><span>15.6"</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">CPU type</div><span>Intel Core i7 12th Gen</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Memory</div><span>16GB</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Storage</div><span>1 TB PCIe</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">GPU</div><span>NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Resolution</div><span>1920 x 1080</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Weight</div><span>4 - 4.9 lbs.</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Backlit Keyboard</div><span>Backlit</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Touchscreen</div><span>No</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">CPU Speed</div><span>12650H (2.30GHz)</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Number of Cores</div><span>10-core (6P+4E) Processor</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Color</div><span>Black</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Display Type</div><span>Full HD</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Graphic Type</div><span>Dedicated Card</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Operating System</div><span>Windows 11 Home</span></td>
    <td class="td-spec"><div class="hid-text">Webcam</div><span>Yes</span></td>
    <td class="td-action">
        <div class="item-action grid col-w-3">
            <div class="goods-price-current hide-click-for-details">
                <div class="goods-price font-s">
                    <div class="goods-price-current">
                        <span class="goods-price-label"></span>
                        <span class="goods-price-symbol">$</span>
                        <span class="goods-price-value"><strong>1,159</strong><sup>.00</sup></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="goods-operate xxs-hide">
                <div class="goods-button-area">
                    <label class="input-check input-check-s compare-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" aria-label="checkbox">
                        <span class="input-check-mark text-hide">checkmark</span>
                        <div class="input-check-text">Compare</div>
                    </label>
                    <button title="Add MSI Katana 15 B12VGK-082US 15.6&quot; 144 Hz IPS Intel Core i7 12th Gen 12650H (2.30GHz) NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU 16GB Memory 1 TB NVMe SSD Windows 11 Home 64-bit Gaming Laptop to cart" class="button button-s bg-orange">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As i am just learning to scrape i scraped only title and screen size for just one laptop
Below is my scrapy code

```
import scrapy

class LaptopSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "laptop"
    headers = {
        "authority": "ssl.doas.state.ga.us",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"92\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"92\"",
        "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "origin": "https://ssl.doas.state.ga.us",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "referer": "https://ssl.doas.state.ga.us/gpr/",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    }
    start_urls = ['https://www.newegg.com/tools/laptop-finder']
    custom_settings = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False}
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def parse(self, response):
        product = response.css('tr td.td-item')

        for item in product:
            yield {
                'Title': item.css('.goods-title-content::text').get(),
                'Screen Size': item.xpath('.//div[text()="Screen Size"]/following-sibling::span/text()').get(),
            }
```

My log file is

```
2023-09-10 10:12:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-09-10 10:12:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-09-10 10:12:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-09-10 10:12:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https://www.newegg.com/tools/laptop-finder> (referer: None)
2023-09-10 10:12:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-09-10 10:12:29 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (0 items) in: j.json
2023-09-10 10:12:29 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to handle 302 redirect in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795416/how-to-handle-302-redirect-in-scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to give a clear, direct answer to this question.

You need to take this knowledge as a base:

1. 302 status means redirect. Typically this can be used by the server to set cookies. Therefore, there is no need to disable redirects and enable 302 response processing.
2. You can use ways to debug your code https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html
3. I would recommend using the start_requests initial method to pass your headers into the first request for the url https://www.newegg.com/tools/laptop-finder